# Chat/comments window appears in Potplayer?

Tags: daum-pot-player

Several days ago I updated my potplayer. Beside the few changes that the update did like changing what key does what.

The most annoying thing happened. Every time I go full screen (either by enter or by double clicking) a small black window appears in the middle of the screen. That window is called chats/comments. I cannot find anything about that window on the Web or in the player's settings. How do I remove it?

Comment: Interesting name for a program. I just downloaded and started to use it. Could you screenshot the chat/comments window so I know what I'm looking for? Does this occur for videos being played from your computer or are you playing them online somehow?

Comment: here, i made a very poorly gif... if this helps :D http://gph.is/1QAduyD

Answer (score 3):

Go to
Preferences (F5) > General > 
Uncheck following option:
"Use various browser when you don't chat in the chat area"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by changing the skin to default or [built in skin]. It's in Menu > Skins.

Answer (score 0):

oh it,s very easy. there is a blue arrow on chatting room.you should click on it. it will hidden. if you want remove chatting and black window completely you can click arrow on edge of black window. it will hide until you appear it again

Comment: This reads like a google translation. Please improve the grammar.